# PHP store time as var help !

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi this is my first post here, I am using:

```
$server_time = gettimeofday(True);
```

to retrieve time to store in phpMyAdmin. at the same time I want to store it in to a non changeable value variable., making sure the time stored in phpMyAdmin is exactly he same as the non changeable value variable, how do I do so ?

Next is I need to store the logout time in to the same id line in phpMyadmin where I first stored the `$server_time = gettimeofday(True);`. But how do I know what id it was stored in ? when there are literally many people logging in ?

Comment: Why are you generating the time in PHP instead of just using NOW() in your SQL?

Comment: I did not know I could do that.

Comment: Agree with @Paul Schreiber; using NOW() and the user id and inserting them into the DB would accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: So I have to manually specify a user id ? If possible i would like to track the id that was auto incremented for the sake of loging. Even with an ID inserted manually php could return an error, due to the amount of people logging in.

Comment: If they are logged in, a `_SESSION` could exist. That's your ID. At least for the Logging out part. If you want to record the time of which they Log In, just execute an `INSERT` command after the Log In procedure; within the same PHP.

Comment: dude _SESSION is deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php, any other options ?

Comment: $HTTP_SESSION_VARS is deprecated. $_SESSION is the preferred form.

Answer (score 0):

Digi

I have run into this myself.  Paul is right.  You should use the NOW() if you don't want all items being entered to have the same stamp (like a batch number).  I use two solutions.  If I want to ensure that the wrong user doesn't get someone elses ID then I do Example 2.  But example one is my first option instead of using PHP's built in function.

```
<?php

$sql_in = "INSERT INTO `table` ( `id` , `stamp` , `user`  ) 
            VALUES (
            NULL , NOW( ) , '".addslashes($name)."' )"; 
$result_in = @mysql_query($sql_in, $GLOBALS['database']) or die(mysql_error());
$sql_in = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as 'insertedId' FROM `table`"; 
$result_in = @mysql_query($sql_in, $GLOBALS['mainFrame']) or die(mysql_error());
$row_InsertedId = mysql_fetch_array($result_in);
$saveid = $row_InsertedId[insertedId];

?>
```

Creating a md5 unique so you can call it back to find the Unique ID auto generated.

```
<?php

// uniquesessionid

$uniqueKey = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));

$sql_in = "INSERT INTO `table` ( `id` , `stamp` , `user`, `tempkey`  ) 
        VALUES (
        NULL , NOW( ) , '".addslashes($name)."', '$uniqueKey'   )"; 
$result_in = @mysql_query($sql_in, $GLOBALS['database']) or die(mysql_error());

// ID
$sql_in = "SELECT `id` FROM `table`" WHERE `tempKey` = '$uniqueKey' LIMIT 1; 
$result_in = @mysql_query($sql_in, $GLOBALS['mainFrame']) or die(mysql_error());
$row_InsertedId = mysql_fetch_array($result_in);
$saveid = $row_InsertedId[insertedId];

?>
```

Hope this helps.